# Angular code from ng-book

Tags: angularjs

I'm reading the ng-book and there's some code I'm not quite following:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <input ng-model="expr" type="text" placeholder="Enter an expression" />
  <h2>{{ parsedValue }}</h2>
</div>

angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller('MyController',
function($scope, $parse) {
  $scope.$watch('expr', function(newVal, oldVal, scope) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
      // Let's set up our parseFun with the expression
      var parseFun = $parse(newVal);
      // Get the value of the parsed expression
      $scope.parsedValue = parseFun(scope);
    }
  });
});
```

I'm guessing parseFun() evaluates scope.expr.  If that is the case how does it know to evaluate this property?

Answer (score 0):

parseFun is $parse(newVal)
In this case they are implying that this means parseFun will be a new parsed expression. Then they retrieve the value of the parsed expression by passing the scope given from the watch function callback with parseFun(scope)

Note: in actual angular development you will rarely find the need to use a watch statement in a controller.